MongoDB Kotlin Driver : Client timeout after a few hours
I'm using the MongoDB Kotlin Driver dependency.
My project run with Spring Boot but I don't want to use the Spring Data MongoDB dependency (So as not to be dependant on Spring).
I use a bean to provide the db client :
    @Bean("mongoClient")
    fun mongoClient(
        dm: IDataManager,
        @Value("\${db.url:${DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL}}") ipAddress: String
    ): MongoClient {

        val codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromProviders(
                KotlinSerializerCodecProvider(
                    dm.serializersModule + org.bson.codecs.kotlinx.defaultSerializersModule
                ),
            ),
            MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
//            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(ZonedDateTimeCodec(), URICodec()),
        )

        val settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(ConnectionString(ipAddress))
            .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
            .build()

        log.info("Mongo DB connection configured to $ipAddress.")
        return MongoClient.create(settings);
    }

My client is disconnected after a few hours, and I don't know how to reconnect it / keep the connection alive. I know it's possible to set a bigger timeout value, but I don't want to use this method (or only if it's the only way to do it).
Is it possible to keep the connection alive ?
Edit :
There is my error :
2024-10-22T20:34:26.288Z  INFO 1 --- [null'}-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server db:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:265) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:235) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:221) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:113) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException: null
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$1.run(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:473) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted

My docker-compose file :
name: spring-project
services:
  reverse_proxy:
    image: nginx:1.26.0-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend

  frontend:
    image: "frontend:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    restart: always

  backend:
    image: "backend-server:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=backend-admin
      - spring.ldap.urls=ldap://********
      - spring.ldap.domain=*********
      - spring.security.user.name=*******
      - spring.security.user.password=*******
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:7.0-ubuntu2204
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_data:/data/db


I have not received any timeout ever with mongo.What is the symptom of the connection timeout?  Where is your DB local, or in a remote hosting solution (where perhaps the connection to that place is liable to timeout)?  Have you tried keep a Mongo Shell open to the same server and see if that times out?

@AndrewL I've just updated my message with the error log. This happens randomly and there are between 4 and 8 hours between timeouts.
My database is running in docker with the image “mongodb/mongodb-community-server:7.0-ubuntu2204”, in the same stack as my Spring application.

I cannot answer the question, but I notice quite a bit of talk in places like the following links which suggest that the connection may need to be kept alive. (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DRIVERS-383 and  https://medium.com/solving-mongodb-connection-drop-issues-by-tuning/solving-mongodb-connection-drop-issues-by-tuning-tcp-keep-alive-settings-eb179cab972c) I suppose I have been insulated by this by using a Spring driver.  If you don't get answers from others, you could dip into the Spring Driver source code
